# Powershell LDAP Filter with DirectorySearcher

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I am using the `DirectorySearcher` class to find a single user. The criteria should be that the `objectCategory` is a user, and that his password is **not set to never expires**.

After some searching, I have come up with this:

```
$searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher

$searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$env:username)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)))"
```

where `userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536` should be for users whose password never expires.

Finally I do:

```
$user = $searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
```

But it says that I cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. I think I am using the parentheses correctly. So then could it be that I can't use the ! operator for this?

Also note that I could use the `get-aduser` command, like so:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties samAccountName, PasswordNeverExpires | where { $_.passwordNeverExpires -eq "true" } | where {$_.enabled -eq "true"} | where {$_.samAccountName -eq $env:username}
```

but in this instance it would be preferable to use the `DirectorySearcher` instead like shown above.

Comment: Your search work fine on my computer (Windows 7 : PS 5.0)

Comment: @JPBlanc I have PSVersion 3.0, it's an old server

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to use `Get-ADUser` cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your code is working, but when the `$searcher.FindOne(`) return nothing, that is to say, when the filter return nothing, the `GetDirectoryEntry()` method give :

> ```
> > You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:1 char:1
> > + $searcher.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
> > + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
> >     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
> ```

Try :

```
$user = $searcher.FindOne()
if($user -ne $null) {$user.GetDirectoryEntry()} else {write-host "Niet"}
```

Comment: Calling `.FindOne()` twice is wasteful in itself. `$user = $searcher.FindOne(); if ($user) { $user.GetDirectoryEntry() } else { Write-Host "Niet" }`

Comment: @Tomalak  You are absolutly right. I edited my answer this way.